# Safe conversion to tuple/list

Tags: python

I have a tuple `y = (3,4)` which I want to append to every element of a list `z`.

If `z` contains single elements I can do:

```
>>> z = [1, 2]
>>> [(x, ) + y for x in z]
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

And if `z` contains tuples I can do:

```
>>> z = [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> [x + y for x in z]
[(0, 1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

But *if I don't know* in advance whether `z` is single elements or tuples/lists, how can I proceed?

I've tried:

```
>>> z = [1, 2]
>>> [tuple(x) + y for x in z]
```

But that gives me:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Clearly I could make a function which tests for tupleness:

```
In [38]: def tuplify(x):
   ....:     try:
   ....:         return tuple(x) # This is 'transparent' if x is already a tuple
   ....:     except TypeError:
   ....:         return (x, )
```

but that seems rather inelegant. What's a nice way to proceed?

*Note: this whole question  could equally be asked about lists too*

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, thanks. I know it's important to accept an answer, but I'm not completely certain we've got arrived at the best possible answer for this question. But maybe we have. I'll give it a bit longer then accept.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a one-liner, this:

```
[x + y if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
```

will work for you.

Here's the results from trying both a list and a list of tuples:

```
>>> y = (3,4)
>>> z = [1, 2]
>>> [x + y if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
>>> z = [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> [x + y if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[(0, 1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

This will work if `y` is a list:

```
[x + y if isinstance(x, list) else [x] + y for x in z]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get `isinstance` to cover tuples *and* lists?

Comment: @LondonRob I've been trying to figure something out. The problem is that `.append()/.extend()` can't be used in a list comp.

Comment: @LondonRob I added a case for a list, I'm working on one that will work for list or tuple in one list comp.

Comment: @LondonRob, @Morgan Thrapp, How about using `hasattr(x, '__iter__')` to cover iterables as a whole?

Comment: @dsoosh Oooo, that's even better. Thanks!

Comment: Only problem with testing for an iterable is that `str` is also an iterable, as are dictionaries. I doubt turning them into tuples is desired behaviour. eg. `tuple("abc") == ("a", "b", "c")`.

Comment: @Dunes According to OP this only needs to work with lists/tuples. Though I guess it would fail if it was a flat list/tuple of strings. :/

Comment: @MorganThrapp I'm saying that strings and dictionaries should be considered single elements. Yet they both have `__iter__` methods.

Comment: @Dunes Yeah, I see what you mean. I rolled back my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Just because this was asked in the comments -

> Is there a way to get isinstance to cover tuples and lists?

Yes, there is a way to cover both lists and tuples and other types of iterables. You can check the isinstance against [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable) . Example to show both lists and tuples are `Iterable` -

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> isinstance(list(),Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(tuple(),Iterable)
True
```

Your code would look like -

```
from collections import Iterable
[x + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
```

If you want the inner list to always be `tuple` you can do -

```
from collections import Iterable
[tuple(x) + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
```

So that even if `inner` list of `z` is list, it would become tuple before y is appended to it. This is because trying to concatenate `x` and `y` would throw error.

If the type of both `y` and `z` cannot be determined at compile time , the you can convert both `y` and `z` to tuple in the list comprehension , like -

```
from collections import Iterable
[tuple(x) + tuple(y) if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + tuple(y) for x in z]
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> y = (3,4)
>>> z = [1,2]
>>> [x + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
>>> y = (3,4)
>>> z = [(1,2),(2,3)]
>>> [x + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 3, 4)]
>>> y = (3,4)
>>> z = [[1,1],[2,2]]
>>> y = [3,4]
>>> z = [[1,1],[2,2]]
>>> [x + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> y = (3,4)
>>> z = [[1,1],[2,2]]
>>> [tuple(x) + y if isinstance(x, Iterable) else (x, ) + y for x in z]
[(1, 1, 3, 4), (2, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: What if `y` is a list?

Comment: I added a case for that as well, it would convert everything to tuple, but can be easily modified to convert everything to list.

Comment: There is a problem if `x` is a string, dictionary or any other iterable that would normally be considered a single element. `Sequence` would be better, but that still includes strings. `isinstance(x, (tuple, list))` would probably be best.